# Finding corresponding values from already subsetted vectors in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector, subset

Background: I have my dataset as a **csv** file called `D` (*please load it to your R*):

```
D = read.csv("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B5V8AyEFBTmXWU40TUZGTURQWlU&export=download")
```

I use the following function to obtain **2 quantities** from my data (*please source to your R*):

```
source("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B5V8AyEFBTmXWTk0LWhaMkY2b3M&export=download")
```

The 2 quantities are obtained as follows:

```
b = BF.d.pvalue(t = D$t.value, n1 = D$n1, n2 = D$n2)
BF = b[1, ]  ;  p.value = b[2, ]
```

Subsetting Details: I have subsetted `p.value` larger than `.05` and their corresponding `BF`s:

```
 pvalue.05_1 = p.value[p.value > .05] ;
 BF.pvalue.05_1 = BF[p.value > .05]`
```

I have further subsetted `BF.pvalue.05_1` that are between `1/10` and `1/3`:

```
BF.pvalue.05_1_.1_.33 = BF.pvalue.05_1[BF.pvalue.05_1 > 1/10 & BF.pvalue.05_1 <= 1/3]
```

Question: Now I'm wondering how I can find the corresponding `p.value` for `BF.pvalue.05_1_.1_.33` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to do this is to combine your data to a `dataframe` and then using the `subset` command for filtering.

```
myDf = data.frame(p = p.value, BF = BF)
head(myDf)
#              p            BF
# 1 2.274873e-06  6.241835e+03
# 2 3.811612e-02  1.736017e+00
# 3 0.000000e+00 2.592434e+147
# 4 0.000000e+00 1.982820e+130
# 5 0.000000e+00  1.315152e+29
# 6 9.992007e-15  4.442134e+11
```

Now, whenever you subset your data *rowwise*, you will have access to both the `p` value and the `BF` value.

```
firstSubset = subset(myDf, p > .05)
dim(firstSubset)
# [1] 175   2

secondSubset = subset(firstSubset, BF > .1 & BF < 1/3)
dim(secondSubset)
# [1] 76  2

head(secondSubset)
#            p        BF
# 28 0.8518770 0.3131790
# 34 0.9358011 0.2910234
# 35 0.9302671 0.2911639
# 52 0.6825720 0.3101911
# 88 0.7201547 0.2770751
# 96 0.6472360 0.2868055
```

Alternatively, you can use both conditions simultaniousely

```
secondSubset = subset(myDf, (BF > .1) & (BF < 1/3) & (p > .05))
```

Comment: Nope, The negation of (`A` *and* `B`) is (not `A` *or* not `B`). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: I'm just saying if you negate (`(p>.05)` and `BF>.1`) you get (`(p<=.05)` or `BF<=.1`). What you do with that is up to you.

Comment: If you have another question, ask a new question. This might be more related to logic/maths I assume. So check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320678/de-morgans-theorem-for-3-variables) and then post your new question in [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)